# Extracting lines that has match in the first column?

Tags: awk, string, search

I have two files:

file 1:

```
a,txt1,v1
b,txt2,v2
c,txt3,v1
d,txt4,v2
```

file2:

```
a,txt5,v2
b,txt6,v1
xc,txt7,v1
xd,txt8,v2
```

I want to refine the files. I only need the lines where the 1st column in `file1` has match in `file2`.

The new file1 should contain:

```
a,txt1,v1
b,txt2,v2
```

Similarly, `file2` should be refined to contain only lines where there is a match in the 1st column with `file1`. So file2 should be:

```
a,txt5,v2
b,txt6,v1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Bash script that should do what you want:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# match.sh

file1="$1"
file2="$2"

while read line; do
    column="$(echo "${line}" | cut -d, -f1)"
    if grep -Pq "^${column}," "${file2}"; then
        echo "${line}"
    fi
done < "${file1}"
```

You would run it like this:

```bsh
user@host:~$ bash match.sh file1 file2
a,txt1,v1
b,txt2,v2

user@host:~$ bash match.sh file2 file1

a,txt5,v2
b,txt6,v1
```

And here's a Python script that does essentially the same thing:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""match.py"""

import sys
import csv

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file1:
    reader1 = csv.reader(file1)
    for row1 in reader1:
        with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as file2:
            reader2 = csv.reader(file2)
            for row2 in reader2:
                if row1[0] == row2[0]:
                    print(','.join(row1))
                    break
```